# Possible memory leak in FindMinimum? (MMA v10.0)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, memory

So I was running some code when I noticed Mathematica was gulping memory, and after some debugging I think the culprit is found. It turned out the function `FindMinimum` had something to do with it.

Let me show you my problem by the following example, running the following code,

```
$HistoryLength = 1;
MemoryInUse[] 10.^-6
(*22.2081*)
```

Checking the memory usage in an empty Notebook, which turned out to be 22MB. Executing the `FindMinimum` function a bunch of times will let us monitor it's memory consumption.

```
Do[f[n] = FindMinimum[(x - RandomReal[])^2, {x, .5, 0, 1}, MaxIterations -> 7][[2, 1, 2]];, {n, 0, 100000}];
MemoryInUse[] 10.^-6
(*64.492*)
Clear[f]
MemoryInUse[] 10.^-6
(*47.525*)
```

Apparently this claims around (64MB-22MB=) 42MB of memory, but the same amount is not freed when clearing `f`, (64MB-47MB=) 17MB is a lot smaller than 42MB. This results in 25MB lingering memory. And repeating this will increase this amount by an additional 25MB per iteration.

Now testing this without the `FindMinimum` gives the expected result,

```
Do[f[n] = RandomReal[];, {n, 0, 100000}];
MemoryInUse[] 10.^-6
(*64.4933*)
Clear[f]
MemoryInUse[] 10.^-6
(*47.525*)
```

This implies saving the definition of 100.000 variables takes 17MB memory, and clearing them releases 17MB of the memory, and no extra memory is lost.

---

**The Question**

Is there a bug in `FindMinimum`? Or is it purposely saving data, and so, is there a way of clearing this?

---

I'am running MMA 10.0 under Mac OS X 10.11

Comment: With Mathematica 10.3.1 on Windows 10 the memory usage returns to its original value (to within <1MB) following the `Clear[f]`

Comment: Don't add the "bugs" tag until confirmed

Comment: Can't repro with Mma v9,Win32

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the problem with 10.0.2 on OS X, even in command line mode.  Both 10.2.0 and 10.3.1 are free of the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs that is good to hear, seems I will have to update to 10.3. Thank you all for checking so fast.

Comment: I can reproduce it on MMA10.0 (Windows 8.1 64 bits)